# JavaFX controls not found in Android using Gluon

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, graalvm

I was under the impression that some or all of JavaFX can be compiled using Gluon and the resulting APK can run successfully on Android. [The HelloFXML example](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloFXML) in the Gluon samples demonstrates this, but it uses only a button and a label, it works fine.

So I played with that then decided to try some other controls, but to date both Menu and Combobox controls result in errors when the APK is run on the Android device, though they work fine on the desktop.

(Please understand I am trying to run bog-standard JavaFX, I am not currently trying to use Charm.)

So, there is no problem compiling the code and generating the APK, but when uploaded, this log comes back from the Android device, and the screen remains blank:

```
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25817 E GraalGluon: called JavaMainWrapper_run
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2701)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2943)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2787)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2752)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2618)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3317)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3274)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3243)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3216)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at hellofx.HelloFXML.start(HelloFXML.java:42)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:849)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:100)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     ... 3 more
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.ComboBox
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:64)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:290)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:3011)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:3000)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2941)
06-23 07:44:08.009 25791 25816 D GraalCompiled:     ... 20 more
```

The JavaFX fxml file contains reference to a ComboBox, correctly imported. The POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <main.class>hellofx.HelloFXML</main.class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
        <charm.version>6.0.6</charm.version>
        <glisten.afterburner.version>2.0.5</glisten.afterburner.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.11</attach.version>
        <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
        <gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>1.0.1</gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.gluonhq.samples</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>hellofxml</artifactId>
    
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestApplication</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    <bundlesList>
                        <list>hellofx.hello</list>
                    </bundlesList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>hellofx.HelloController</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The application runs correctly on the desktop.

So, I guess my question is: Am I doing something wrong, or are my expectations of Gluon too high?

Comment: Did you run `mvn gluonfx:runagent`?

Comment: Not all classes that you reference via FXML are added to native image by default. You can either add them manually to the reflection list or better, as José has already suggested, run the agent to identify these missing classes.